# Prove $(n + 1)I(n) = (n + 2)I(n + 2)$ by integration by parts.

Tags: real-analysis, integration

$I_n$ is given by $\int ^ {\pi/2}_{0}  \sin^n(x) dx$

My attempt: I got to the fact that the statement is true iff $$\dfrac {n+1}{n+2} = 
\int ^ {\pi/2}_{0} \dfrac {\sin^2(x)}{\sin^n(x)}$$

I do not know how to prove the above statement using integration by parts.

Comment: Your "iff" is incorrect. You can't willy-nilly rearrange integrals like that (with regards to division).

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_reduction_formulae#Examples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an outline:
$$I_{n+2}=\int_0^{\pi/2}(\sin^{n+1}x)(\sin x)\,dx
  =\int_0^{\pi/2}u\frac{dv}{dx}\,dx\ ,$$
where
$$u=\sin^{n+1}x\ ,\quad \frac{dv}{dx}=\sin x\ .$$
Now apply the integration by parts formula: there is a bit of algebra to do but if you do it slowly and carefully you should end up with
$$I_{n+2}=(n+1)\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^nx\cos^2x\,dx\ .$$
Now use $\cos^2x=1-\sin^2x$, expand and look carefully at the two integrals you get.  See if you can explain why we now have
$$I_{n+2}=(n+1)I_n-(n+1)I_{n+2}\ .$$
Now treat this as an equation, move all the $I_n$ terms to the RHS and all the others to the LHS.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks  david. Your response was extremely helpful!