# Prove that $\lim_{m\to\infty} I_{2m}/I_{2m+1}=1$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

$I_n$ is given by $\int ^ {\pi/2}_{0}  \sin^n(x)\, dx$

Prove $I_{2m+1} \leq I_{2m} \leq (1+ \frac {1}{2m}) I_{2m+1}$. Also prove $\displaystyle \lim_{m\to\infty} \frac {I_{2m}}{I_{2m+1}}=1$.

I'm having trouble approaching this problem. I know I need to prove $\int ^{\pi/2}_{0}  \sin^{2m+1}x- \sin^{2m}x \leq 0$ I tried plugging this integral into wolfram alpha with $m=2$, and to show that it is less than 0, it used the reduction formula many times. I would appreciate a better way of showing the inequality. Help on the limit part of the proof would also be appreciated.

---

Update: I now only need help proving $I_{2m} \leq (1+ \frac {1}{2m}) I_{2m+1}$

Comment: $I_{2m+1} \leq I_{2m}$ is trivial because $0 \leq \sin(x) \leq 1$ on that interval.

Comment: For the final result, you can use the result proved [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1047772/prove-n-1in-n-2in-2-by-integration-by-parts), which happened to be your own question. The idea is to express $I(2m)$ in terms of $I(0)$ and $I(2m+1)$ in terms of $I(1)$.

Comment: See [Wallis' integrals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis'_integrals).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the other inequality, note that, by integrating by parts,

$$I_{2m+1}=-\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^{2m}x(\cos x)'\,dx=\int_0^{\pi/2}(\sin^{2m}x)'\cos x\,dx=2m\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^{2m-1}x\cos^2x\,dx=2m\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^{2m-1}x(1-\sin^2x)\,dx=2mI_{2m-1}-2mI_{2m+1},$$

which gives that $\left(1+\frac{1}{2m}\right)I_{2m+1}=I_{2m-1}\geq I_{2m}$.

Answer (score 1):

Showing that the limit is 1 follows from the squeeze theorem. Just divide the given inequality through by $I_{2m+1}$ to get
$$1 \le \frac{I_{2m}}{I_{2m+1}} \le 1+\frac{1}{2m}$$
and take the limit as $m\to\infty$.

The lower bound follows from that fact that $0 \le \sin(x) \le 1$ on $[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$. 
Multiply "$\sin(x)\le 1$" by $\sin^n(x)$ to get $\sin^{n+1}(x) \le \sin^n(x)$; integrate from $0$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$ to get $I_{n+1} \le I_n$.

The upper bound follows by parts.
In the integral for $I_{n+1}$ let $u = \sin^n(x)$ and $dv = \sin(x)\,dx$.
Then $du = n\sin^{n-1}(x)\cos(x)\,dx$ and $v = -\cos(x)$.
Integrate by parts to get 
$$I_{n+1} = \sin^n(x)(-\cos(x))\Big|_0^{\pi/2} + n \int_0^{\pi/2}\cos^2(x) \sin^{n-1}(x)\,dx.$$
The constant is 0 since $\sin(0) = \cos(\pi/2) = 0$. Rewrite the $\cos^2(x)$ in the integrand as $1 - \sin^2(x)$ to get 
$$I_{n+1} = n\int_0^{\pi/2} (1-\sin^2(x))\sin^{n-1}(x)\,dx = n (I_{n-1} - I_{n+1})$$
from which it follows that $\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right) I_{n+1} = I_{n-1}$, which is $\ge I_n$ by the already-proven lower bound.